# Showing Category Count on Html Links

Tags: php, html, wordpress

I have html links on my wordpress website sidebar and I would like to show the number of posts related to that link.

The posts are placed under custom listing category defined by the following function:

Php:

```
function va_cat_menu_drop_down( $location = 'menu', $taxonomy ) {
global $va_options;

$key = 'categories_' . $location;
$options = $va_options->$key;

$args['menu_cols'] = ( $location == 'menu' ? 3 : 2 );
$args['menu_depth'] = $options['depth'];
$args['menu_sub_num'] = $options['sub_num'];
$args['cat_parent_count'] = $options['count'];
$args['cat_child_count'] = $options['count'];
$args['cat_hide_empty'] = $options['hide_empty'];
$args['cat_nocatstext'] = true;
$args['cat_order'] = 'ASC';
$args['taxonomy'] = $taxonomy;

$terms_args['pad_counts'] = false;
$terms_args['app_pad_counts'] = true;

return va_categories_list($args, $terms_args);
}
```

How can I show that number of posts in a particular category next to my Html link as the following does not work (I guess as the listing category is probably custom taxonomy?)

```
<?php echo get_category(17)->count; ?>
```

Answer (score 0):

There is a very simple method to do this. Use wp_list_categories and enter the argument 'show_count' => 1

```
http://codex.wordpress.org/Template_Tags/wp_list_categories
```

Comment: thanks..but this counts the number or posts under the blog category and not under the listing category..any thoughts on how i can achieve this?